# For MVVM in Xamarin.Forms, which is better? Common views or Platform specific views?

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I'm just starting with Xamarin. I wanted to know which approach is more suitable for MVVM Xamarin.Forms app:

1. Keeping the User Interface views common for iOS, Android and WP8.1 or platform specific?
2. Which one will be easier (as there's no UI designer for Xamarin's XAML)?
3. Which one will be easier for data binding?

Answer (score 2):

There were several questions within your post:

***Keeping the User Interface views common for iOS, Android and WP8.1 or platform specific?***

This is entirely dependent on what you are trying to achieve. Xamarin.Forms is a very usable option for a whole range of solutions but is not a 'catch all' solution. Read up on the limitations and make this decision based on your project's requirements.

***Which one will be easier (as there's no UI designer for Xamarin's XAML)?***

All of the options carry their own particular learning curve and there is no right or wrong answer. Irrespective of which approach you will take there will be a requirement to understand the underlying native implementation.

***Which one will be easier for data binding?***

The implementations you have described will have no bearing on how you utilise data bindings.

I would recommend reading through the developer documentation on the Xamarin site and making an informed decision on how to proceed.

Comment: About data binding, if I create a Native UI for each platform, wont I need to bind the `List` or `ObservableCollection` on each UI separately?

Answer (score 1):

Jordan has a very good answer, but I would like to add that there are easy ways to create platform specific looks without having to do a lot of work using Style, that you can write at the top of the application level. If you decide to take the route of custom looks, I would suggest you look there.

I personally think that the XAML is easier to use, but I also have Resharper 9 to give me intellisense. This keeps my pages a lot cleaner and shorter, since only the logic that is needed for the page are in the page.

As for data binding, I think they are approximately the same amount of work.

Here is a really good book that has much of resources you may want to start writing a Xamarin Forms application. [Xamarin.Forms Book Preview 2](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/preview-2/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the book. I didnt get the first part though. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This link should give you a good idea of how to use styles in your code. [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/)